# Why do the border colors change on click?

Tags: html, css, colors, outline

I'm trying to make a search -box with categories, like Amazon. The problem is that, when I click inside the text area, the borders change color creating a bad view effect. How can I stop it?

Here is the code:

```css
$border-color: orange;
#form-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.nav-list {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

#dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
}

#dropdown:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.current-selection {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.in-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#search-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.go-button {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.go-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 115, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <button class="go-button fa fa-search"></button>
  <span class="nav-list">
  <span class="current-selection">
  </span>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="books-and-ebooks">Books & eBooks</option>
    <option value="audiobooks">Audiobooks</option>
    <option value="dvds">DVDs</option>
    <option value="other-resources">Other Resources</option>
    <option value="random">Random</option>
  </select>
  </span>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="search-box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I realized that on JSFiddle is not working the same way as on codepen, so here is on codepen: http://codepen.io/1z10/pen/QEbjBx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening because the browsers add ***outline*** on input field, to fix this you need to remove on ***input:focus*** the attribute ***outline***, declaring this equals ***none***. Like this CSS code:

```
#search-box:focus{
  outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you. I just changed the height...

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<style>



    $border-color: orange;
    #form-wrapper {
      width: 50%;
      height: 40px;
    }

    .nav-list {
      padding: 10px 25px 10px 5px;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid $border-color;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    }

    #dropdown {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      height: 36px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid $border-color;
    }

    #dropdown:hover {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    .current-selection {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
   textarea:focus, input:focus{
         outline: none;
 }
    .in-wrap {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #search-box {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      border: 1px solid $border-color;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
      line-height: 25px;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding-left: 100px;
    }

    .go-button {
      float: right;
      height: 36px;
      background-color: orange;
      border: 1px solid $border-color;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 15px;
    }

    .go-button:hover {
      background-color: rgb(255, 115, 0);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<div id="form-wrapper">
  <button class="go-button fa fa-search"></button>
  <span class="nav-list">
  <span class="current-selection">
  </span>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="books-and-ebooks">Books & eBooks</option>
    <option value="audiobooks">Audiobooks</option>
    <option value="dvds">DVDs</option>
    <option value="other-resources">Other Resources</option>
    <option value="random">Random</option>
  </select>
  </span>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="search-box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: modified now check once.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the height. The input text fields have a focus attribute that need to be overridden.

Comment: in last update i given correct for focus verify once the code. previously i thought its alignment issue. the code working fine.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
#search-box:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question ii does not provide any details on why and how it is solving the initial problem. This renders the answer less useful for similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use `outline:none;` for disabling the focus outline. You are killing accessibility of the web if you do this. There is a accessible way of doing this.

Check out [this article](https://www.sitebase.be/disable-focus-outline-without-breaking-accessibility/) that I've written to explain how to do this correct without breaking you page for a certain segment of your users.